# Plot both validation and training accuracy using Custom Estimators

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

So i'm using this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators) to create my own custom estimator and I can't get the tensorboard to draw both validation accuracy during the training process. This [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18858) on Github perfectly describes my problem. As someone mentioned in the last comment by setting `save_checkpoints_steps`
to a small value, the model should do evaluation at each step, However that's not the case for me. after I run:

```
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
  model_fn=my_model,
  params={
      'n_classes': 4,
  },
  model_dir=model_dir_str,
  config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=int(1)))

loss_hook = early_stopping.stop_if_lower_hook(classifier, "loss", 0.2, model_dir_str + 'loss_eval')
acc_hook = early_stopping.stop_if_no_increase_hook(classifier, "accuracy", 100, model_dir_str + 'acc_eval')
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=input_train_fn, max_steps=steps, hooks=[loss_hook, acc_hook])
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=input_eval_fn, steps=1000)
results = tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(classifier, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

I only get two points in the plot. I have experimented with different values for  and I still get the same results.
[image: Tensorboard plot with save_checkpoints_steps = 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has came up with an answer, I'm posting this messy work-around for the time being.

```
loss_hook = early_stopping.stop_if_lower_hook(classifier, "loss", 0.2, 'loss_eval')
acc_hook = early_stopping.stop_if_no_increase_hook(classifier, "accuracy", 100, 'acc_eval')    
tf.logging.set_verbosity(False)
for i in range(int(steps/10)):
    print(i)
    classifier.train(
        input_fn=input_train_fn,
        steps=10,
        hooks=[loss_hook, acc_hook])
    # Evaluate the model.
    eval_result = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=input_eval_fn, steps=5)
print(eval_result)
```

Basically you run the training for a small number of steps and then do one evaluation.